# Upgrading Android Gradle Plugin to 8.0.0 "jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to upgrade my Android Gradle Plugin to 8.0 with the latest stable Flamingo release.

However, I get this issue after running the AGP upgrade assistant and trying to run the build.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
```

I've updated these lines in the build.gradle files

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
```

However, I'm still getting this issue.

What does this issue mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and changed to the configuration similar to yours, the only difference is that the 17 is in single quotes, like this 
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
And it worked for me

Answer (score 6):

This code snippet syntax is deprecated :

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
}
```

use this instead :

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same issue, even when I double check all of my build gradle files to be updated with this. Is it possible for a dependency to perhaps be relying on version 1.8 which could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Please check your answer, could it be that you are confusing kts with groovy script?

Comment: No, its not kts snippet, I haven't migrated to kts yet. I am using groovy.

Answer (score 5):

Try this: Go to
`File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle` 
and change `Gradle SDK` to match your project java version - 17.

Answer (score 3):

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
}
```

with this setup you can use AGP version 8.0.0.
and also set the Gradle JDK to Embedded KDL in your android studio settings.

finally, clean your build and rebuild again

Answer (score 2):

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

Try to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding ToolChain to the app level gradle file in android block as follow:

```
android {
....
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(8)
  }
}
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task is set to target Java version 1.8, while the 'compileDebugKotlin' task is set to target Java version 17. This mismatch can cause issues during the build process.
you'll need to ensure that the Java version target compatibility for both tasks is set to the same value.u can try updateing the `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```

These might help you

Answer (score 0):

below code works for me

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate caches fixed this for me.