# Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks despite already defining jvm ver

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, java-17

I'm running a flutter project and recently updated a bunch of dependencies.
I'm getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_google_places_sdk_android:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17).

  Consider using JVM Toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
  Learn more about JVM-target validation: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/target-validation
```

I've already updated by build.gradle file to include the following, having already seen these questions

- [How to set compileJava' task ( 11) and 'compileKotlin' task (1.8)
  jvm target compatibility to the same Java version in
  build.gradle.kts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079963/how-to-set-compilejava-task-11-and-compilekotlin-task-1-8-jvm-target-com)
- [Upgrading Android Gradle Plugin to 8.0.0 "jvm target compatibility
  should be set to the same Java
  version"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76069765/upgrading-android-gradle-plugin-to-8-0-0-jvm-target-compatibility-should-be-set)

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
```

However, I still get the above error.
Here's my flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-x64, locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 3.13.6 on channel stable at /Users/sophiahuynh/Documents/_gitLabProjects/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ead455963c (8 weeks ago), 2023-09-26 18:28:17 -0700
    • Engine revision a794cf2681
    • Dart version 3.1.3
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sophiahuynh/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Users/sophiahuynh/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jbrsdk-17.0.9/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-17.0.9+7-1087.3-nomod (build 17.0.9+7-b1087.3)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.76.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)                    • macos         • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 119.0.6045.159

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

- I'm running Java 17.0.9 (incl. my java home, android studio gradle
  jdk)
- I'm running Gradle 8.4 (was running 8.0 before and still facing
  the same issue)
- Kotlin 1.9.20 (also faced the same issue when I was on 1.8.0)

I'm quite lost at what else I can try to do. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: How to solve this issue?

Comment: Might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079963/how-to-set-compilejava-task-11-and-compilekotlin-task-1-8-jvm-target-com?rq=2) can help! Please check,

Answer (score 10):

I was facing same error when upgrading **Gradle** 8.2 and **Kotlin** 1.9.22.

1. Make sure you have the same version here:

   `compileOptions { sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17 targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17 }`

   `kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "17" }`
2. Add in your gralde.properties:
   `kotlin.jvm.target.validation.mode = IGNORE`

This solution maybe doesn't solve the issue but can bypass it until someone fix it.

Only with **step 1** didn't worked.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why do I need to ignore this?

Answer (score -1):

For me the issue was solved by adding this to the general *build.gradle.kts*.

```
   allprojects {
      tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile::class.java).configureEach {
         kotlinOptions {
             jvmTarget = "17"
         }
      }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I get error: "No such property: java for class: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile"