Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' (17) and 'compileReleaseKotlin' (21) flutter 3.27
As of other available questions, I have tried all the solutions but doesn't work. I have update Kotlin to latest version 2.20. My JDK version is 21 and I have also tried with 17. I have tried to update Java home.
How can I resolve it?
My build.gradle as follow:
    plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.giplapp"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = "27.0.12077973"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlin  {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.giplapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

Settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
   id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
   id "com.android.application" version '8.7.3' apply false
   id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
}

include ":app"

I have upgrade Gradle to 8.10.2

You can try this  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77861041/4373661 might help you
